# Using sed or awk to select

Tags: bash, awk, sed, escaping

I'm trying to select the lines between between two markers in an html file. I've tried using sed and awk but I think there's an issue with the way i'm escaping some of the characters. I have seen some similar questions and answers, but the examples given are simple, with no special characters. I think my escaping is the issue. I need the lines between

`<div class="bread crumb">`

and

`</div>`

There is no other div within the block and there are multiple lines within the block.

Do I need to escape the characters `<`, `>` and `?` as below?

```
sed -n -e '/^\<div class=\"bread crumb\"\>$/,/^\<\/div\>$/{ /^\<div class=\"bread crumb\">$/d; /^\<\/div>$/d; p; }'
```

My awk attempt :

```
awk '/\<div class=\"bread crumb\"\>/{flag=1;next}/\<\/div\>/{flag=0}flag'
```

Comment: While `sed` and `awk` might be able to do the job for some input, it is considered bad practice to use non-HTML aware tools to parse HTML. You should have a look at `xpath`, which is a dedicated tool to parse HTML/XML files

Comment: post the initial html fragment and expected result

Comment: obligatory [don't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) link

Answer (score 1):

You should use a html parser for that job.

If you still want to do it with sed, don't escape `<` and `>` that are used for [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Try this:

```
sed -ne '/<div class="bread crumb">/,/<\/div>/{//!p;}' file
```

The `//!p` part outputs all the block except the lines matching the address patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just need to escape the `/` in the `</div>`, rest goes fine..

```
sed -n '/<div class="bread crumb">/,/<\/div>/{//!p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string matches in awk:

```
awk '$0=="</div>"{f=0} f{print} $0=="<div class=\"bread crumb\">"{f=1} ' file
```